# how to count number of children row by family and put the same in the parent rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle database which personal data. I have child_flag from the children and family_id for all the family member.
something like:

```
ID   | birth_date | gender |....| child_flag | family_id
1111 | 2/3/1974   | M      |....| 0          | 1122
1122 | 3/2/1970   | F      |....| 0          | 1122
1133 | 4/4/2000   | F      |....| 1          | 1122
1144 | 5/5/2001   | F      |....| 1          | 1122
1155 | 6/6/2003   | M      |....| 1          | 1122
```

I want to add a new column that contain the number of children (child_flag=1) only on parents (child_flag=0) rows.

```
ID   | birth_date | gender |....| child_flag | family_id | childer_num
1111 | 2/3/1974   | M      |....| 0          | 1122      | 3
1122 | 3/2/1970   | F      |....| 0          | 1122      | 3
1133 | 4/4/2000   | F      |....| 1          | 1122      | 0
1144 | 5/5/2001   | F      |....| 1          | 1122      | 0
1155 | 6/6/2003   | M      |....| 1          | 1122      | 0
....
```

The best result I got was by

```
select *,
case when child_flag=0 then count (ID) over (partition by family_id) else 0 end as chilrden_num
from my_table
```

It give me 5 in parent row and 0 in child row.
But I want to count only child (and got 3). reducing 2 from the sum is not good because I can have 0 or 1 parent row.

any idea how to do it (preferably with-out sub query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the column child_num with default value 0 and then execute the following query.

```
merge into my_table A using (select count(*) as child_count,family_id from my_table where child_flag=1 group by family_id) B on (A.family_id=B.family_id)
when matched then update set A.child_num=B.child_count where child_flag=0;
```

This will give you the expected output.

Comment: Thank you. MERGE can be used when you have to update using sub query. Here you can find the use of MERGE [Example](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a658525f4c7e67749356e3c6da52907)

```
SELECT my_table.*,
CASE 
    WHEN child_flag = 0 THEN 
        SUM(
            CASE 
                WHEN child_flag=0 THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
            END
        ) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id)
    ELSE 0
   END AS chilrden_num
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `child_flag` can only be `0` or `1`, the logic can be simplified to:

```
select t.*,
       (case when child_flag = 0
             then sum(child_flag) over (partition by family_id)
        end) as children_num
from my_table t
```